# HTML email stuck on the write in apple mail

Tags: html, email, send

Beginner at HTML. I have created this html email that displays perfectly fine and central in thunderbird but in Apple Mail, it is stuck on the right, anyone got any ideas?
[this is the email in apple mail that is aligned to the right - I want it in the centre!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFmZg.png)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <title>Fusion CSA Accept Email</title>
    <style type="text/css">

          /* -------------------------------------
              RESPONSIVE AND MOBILE FRIENDLY STYLES
          ------------------------------------- */
          @media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
            table[class=body] h1 {
              font-size: 28px !important;
              margin-bottom: 10px !important;
            }
            table[class=body] p,
                  table[class=body] ul,
                  table[class=body] ol,
                  table[class=body] td,
                  table[class=body] span,
                  table[class=body] a {
              font-size: 16px !important;
            }
            table[class=body] .wrapper,
                  table[class=body] .article {
              padding: 10px !important;
            }
            table[class=body] .content {
              padding: 0 !important;
            }
            table[class=body] .container {
              padding: 0 !important;
              width: 100% !important;
            }
            table[class=body] .main {
              border-left-width: 0 !important;
              border-radius: 0 !important;
              border-right-width: 0 !important;
            }
            table[class=body] .btn table {
              width: 100% !important;
            }
            table[class=body] .btn a {
              width: 100% !important;
            }
            table[class=body] .img-responsive {
              height: auto !important;
              max-width: 100% !important;
              width: auto !important;
            }
          }
          /* -------------------------------------
              PRESERVE THESE STYLES IN THE HEAD
          ------------------------------------- */
          @media all {
            .ExternalClass {
              width: 100%;
            }
            .ExternalClass,
                  .ExternalClass p,
                  .ExternalClass span,
                  .ExternalClass font,
                  .ExternalClass td,
                  .ExternalClass div {
              line-height: 100%;
            }
            .apple-link a {
              color: inherit !important;
              font-family: inherit !important;
              font-size: inherit !important;
              font-weight: inherit !important;
              line-height: inherit !important;
              text-decoration: none !important;
            }
            .btn-primary table td:hover {
              background-color: #34495e !important;
            }
            .btn-primary a:hover {
              background-color: #34495e !important;
              border-color: #34495e !important;
            }
          }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="" style="background-color: #f6f6f6; font-family: sans-serif; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.4; margin: 0; padding: 0; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="body" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%; background-color: #f6f6f6;">
      <tr>
        <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="container" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; display: block; Margin: 0 auto; max-width: 580px; padding: 10px; width: 580px;">
          <div class="content" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: block; Margin: 0 auto; max-width: 580px; padding: 10px;">
            <!-- START CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->
            <span class="preheader" style="color: transparent; display: none; height: 0; max-height: 0; max-width: 0; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all; visibility: hidden; width: 0;">This is preheader text. Some clients will show this text as a preview.</span>
            <table class="main" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%; background: #ffffff; border-radius: 3px;">
              <!-- START MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
              <tr>
                <td class="wrapper" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px;">
                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                      <th>
                        <img src="http://fusiondiscordbots.com/Email Images/icon.png" height="50px" width="100px">
                        <h1 style="font-family: SinkinSans 300Light; font-size: 250%;">Thanks for applying</h1>
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top;">
                        <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 15px; Margin-top: 20px;">Hi [INSERT NAME],</p>
                        <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal;">We would like to thank you for your applciation to become a Fusion Customer Support Agent. After carefully reviewing your application, we have decided to <font color="green"><i><b>Accept</b></i></font> your application. We look forward to welcoming you to the team and working with you in the future.</p>
                        <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal;">In the next 48 hours, we will send you some information about your role. In this information will be some terms that we require you to accept by emailing us back. Once the terms have been accepted, we will announce your new position to the server and give you your new role.</p>
                        <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal;">Well all thats left to say is... Congratulations!</p>
                        <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal;">With appreciation,</p>
                        <img src="http://fusiondiscordbots.com/Email Images/seansignature.png" height="50px">
                        <p style="width: 50%;">Sean Hatch<br>
                          Fusion Managing Director</p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <!-- END CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I just want to be able to send this email to couple of people but I want it to look professional and line up in the centre of all email clients. If anyone could help, it would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Sean.

Answer (score 0):

Your email looks fine in every Apple and IOS email client I looked at in Litmus. The logo and “Thanks for Applying” are not centered in Yahoo! mail.

The biggest issue is that you're not properly formatting your height and width for the logo and the signature graphics.

Instead of this:

`icon.png" height="50px" width="100px"`

Do this:

`icon.png" height="50" width="100"`

Outlook doesn't understand `height="50px"` so the images are the size of the width of the email. That fix and adding a center tag to the table cell for the logo makes your email look great for your recipients.

Good luck to [INSERT NAME] on their new job.

Comment: Yeah I did the Litmus test and sent one through and it worked great but when I try to send it through thunderbird (opens centrally and displays in thunderbird centrally), it comes through to apple mail on the right. Why is this?

Comment: Try sending through http://putsmail.com to your Apple browser and see what happens. It could be that when sending through Thunderbird, it strips some of the CSS out and causes the centering issue. This happens if you send email through clients like Gmail. A feature not supported will not show in a client that supports the feature.

Comment: Yeah it works fine through putsmail but I don't want to pay for putsmail and that is the problem. I need to send it through some kind of free/cheap service.

Comment: Putsmail is currently a free service for testing email. It lets you test a static email without any complications from your sending email client. If sending with Thunderbird works, do that. There could be some limitations with sending that causes it to strip some css, just like with Apple Mail, Gmail, Outlook and others.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used `style="text-align: center;"` as an inline style for the `<tr>` elements to centre content.